# PHP include path, index

Tags: php, html, include, dreamweaver

I know that what I am about to ask is probably extremely simple so please don't be too scathing in your replies...  I am an absolute beginner!

I am building a website using Dreamweaver and PHP, I am currently "slicing" my html code into sections and am saving the sections as "header.php" for example.

So this is where I am stuck, I then in the index.php file am trying to call the header `

Which is not returning any errors in terms of syntax however I then sync all my files onto my web hosting server and the following error gets returned.

> Warning: include(includes/home/public_html/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Sites\XXXXXXXXXX.com\public_html\index.php on line 20 Warning: include(includes/home/public_html/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Sites\XXXXXXXXXX.com\public_html\index.php on line 20 Warning: include(): Failed opening 'includes/home/public_html/header.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\Sites\XXXXXXXXXX.com\public_html\index.php on line 20

I have tried to amend the code to reflect what the error is showing me, or at least I thought I had by writing.

```
<?php include_path='.;C:\php\pear('includes/header.php'); ?>
```

However Dreamweaver is then throwing up that there is a syntax error.

If you need any further information please ask, and thank you in advance for your help, I am trying to learn so forgive my ignorance.

Best wishes

Richard

Update----

So I have now managed to get rid of the errors and am still stuck though, I have the index.php and the header.php file in the same location home/public_html/

in my index.php file I have the following code to return the header.php file.

```
    <body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <?php ('includes/home/public_html/header.php'); ?>
```

now as I mentioned the error has gone but no header is being returned.

Within the header.php file I have the following code,

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <div class="header">

    <div id="header">
        <h2>Welcome</h2>         
    </div>            
    </div> <!-- end #header -->
```

Am I doing something really obviously wrong?

Comment: Right that's it and sorted, thank you for your help you did put me in the right direction and it did pivot around the include function I ended up changing the code syntax to simply being 
        <?php include('header.php'); ?>
and that pulled the file perfectly! 


As ever this community rocks, thanks for everyone who viewed and thank you 

user3122407 for your help. I was going in circles before your response.

Answer (score 0):

Try and use the built include function.

```
<?php
include("includes/header.php"); 
?>
```

is your includes folder in the same directory as the index.php?
there should be no need to change the include path.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is what I started out with and it doesn't seem to work either, just returns the same error in live as above...

Comment: Is your includes folder in the same directory as the index.php? there should be no need to change the include path.

Comment: Your advice has put me on the right path, I think?  I changed the code to `<?php ('includes/home/public_html/header.php'); ?>` this has removed the error message at least.  The only thing is the header.php file is not being shown.